# Dates (Assigning them depending on region)

Tags: javascript, date, discord, discord.js

```
 var d = new Date();
    "**Zone** - `" + 
    d.toTimeString().replace(/\d+:\d+:\d+\s+/, '').replace(/[G][M][T].\d+/, '') + 
    "` **Time** - " +
    "`" + d.toLocaleTimeString() +
    "` **Date** - " + "`" + 
    d.toLocaleDateString() + "`"
```

This is a string of mine which tells me the region, time and date. I am using it on a discord bot and am attempting to make them be different depending on the user's region. I'm not sure how to accomplish this, but for visual example...

The code stated above returns me -

```
Zone - (AUS Eastern Standard Time) Time - 16:49:28 Date - 2018-5-18
```

which I am satisfied with, however, for a test I got a foreign friend to hop on and it sent the same thing when what I am trying to make the result be is their region so...

```
Zone - (AMERICA Western Standard Time) Time - 02:29:09 Date - 2018-5-18
```

Anybody have any ideas?

**EDIT:** Within a new project of mine, I discovered the user of `Intl.DateTimeFormat()` which essentially returns an Array. There is an instance method for this function known as `.resolvedOptions()`, returning an object that has many values within. I simply went ahead and added `.timezone` which returned something similar to "Australia/Queensland".
`var region = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;`

Comment: Is this code run server side or client side? E. g. if it's run by Node.js on some server, the results will be the same for every one because JavaScript takes the servers time.

Comment: In a Discord Server how do you know from what region is the user from? Do you have any database with that information? Because that's not something you have access directly from Discord API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am assuming this code is run in a browser, and not in a server.

You cannot depend on `d.toTimeString()` and cutting out the timezone part to find a timezone, `toTimeString` can return different formats on different browsers. The specs has left the formatting to browser vendors.

You can get the `timezoneOffset` and map it to the timezone name, but wait, there is an issue. This may conflict with Day Light Savings time setting for regions. So you will need a historical set of data for Daylight Savings time all over world.

If you really want to do this, use [moment with timezones](https://momentjs.com/timezone/), which can do the lookup for you and they have already created all mappings including DST for you.

Comment: This is for a Discord Bot. I don't believe you can run the bot on the browser.

Comment: Note that [*ECMAScript 2019*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/) will specify the format of [*Date.prototype.toString*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) and [*toISOString*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring), though it may be some time before support by browsers in use is ubiquitous.